# how to create manifest if bundling and minification is used in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, cache-manifest

ASP.NET MVC4 application MVC4 buildit bundling and minification is used.
Application should work also in offline.

I tried to create manifest using code below but this does not work since v= parameters will change
if source code is changed.
How to create manifest which works without manually changing bundle query string parameters if bundling and minification are used?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="~/Sale/Manifest">

<head>

    @Erp.Helpers.Bundles.Render("~/css/pos", new { media = "screen" })
    @Erp.Helpers.Bundles.Render("~/css/receipt", new { media = "print" })
    @Scripts.Render("~/pos.js")
</head>
```

controller:

```
public ContentResult Manifest()
        {
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = @"CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
pos?v=esdw2223023094323
css/pos?v=ewe3334324r33432343
css/receipt?v=w333543334324r33432343

NETWORK:
*
"
   };
}
```

[C# Web.Optimization Bundles and HTML5 cache Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000676/c-sharp-web-optimization-bundles-and-html5-cache-manifest) contains similar question without answer.

**Update**

I tried answers but got error in chrome console

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (404) http://localhost:52216/erp/Sale/pos.js
```

Application is running using

```
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

and in debug mode by pressing F5 from VSE 2013 for Web

I tried suggestions in answers using

```
public class SaleController : ControllerBase
{

    public ContentResult Manifest()
    {
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = string.Format(@"CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
   {0}
   {1}
   {2}
", 
Scripts.Url("pos.js"),  // tried also Scripts.Url("pos")
Styles.Url("css/pos"),
Styles.Url("css/receipt")),
```

...
   in controller.

view source in browser shows

```
<html manifest="/erp/Sale/Manifest">
<head>
  <link href="/erp/css/pos?v=sN8iz_u3gRGE6MQKGq6KocU-SUIUMcQxKVuESa_L2l41" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="/erp/css/receipt?v=C6qCUe6W1VM6yxNe-RgZRY9R0Gws1vU0lMuoKIn1uVE1" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/>
    <script src="/erp/pos.js?v=a-TsureIIlzxwhaItWMV7Ajfw-YXE3x6hUld3cxwAqI1"></script>
```

generated manifest contains

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
/erp/Sale/pos.js
/erp/Sale/css/pos
/erp/Sale/css/receipt
```

How to fix this ?
It looks like invalid urls are generated to manifest:

1. Sale directory is added
2. Query string is not present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are methods on the Styles and Scripts objects in System.Web.Optimization that will give you the URL of the resource.

You can call `Scripts.Url(string)` to give you the URL of the script file, complete with the hash.  You can also call `Styles.Url(string)` to give you the URL of the style sheet, complete with the hash.

```
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace StackOverflow.Controllers
{
    public class StackOverflowController : Controller
    {
        public ContentResult Manifest()
        {
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = string.Format( 
@"CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
{0}
{1}
{2}

NETWORK:
*
",
 Scripts.Url("~/pos.js"),
 Styles.Url("~/css/pos"),
 Styles.Url("~/css/receipt"))
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The cache-busting hashes will only be added when the site is run with `<compilation debug="false" />` specified in the web.config file.

Comment: Thank you. This sample does not use full bundle name. Should `~/pos.js` used instead of `pos` ? In debug mode bundling is turned off and multiple files are referenced. How to make this work automatically without bundling also ?

Comment: Pervez Choudhury: I tried this but got manifest fetch error. I updated question. How to fix ?

Comment: @Andrus - I've added the relative urls to the code and added a note about when the query string parameters are visible.

Comment: Bundle contains many css and js files. Your solution renders only single file so it will not work in debug mode. Should I use solution from http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/html5-offline-cache-integration-with-asp-dot-net-mvc-bundle ? It looks like this work in debug mode also is it so ?

Answer (score 1):

[Scripts.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scripts.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives you the URL for the bundle, without rendering out the script tags. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I triedt this but got manifest fetch error. I updated question. How to fix ?

Comment: You pass the same thing into Scripts.Url as you do to Scripts.Render - i.e. the name of your bundle. In the above you have "~/pos.js" as the name of your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scripts.RenderFormat` or `Styles.RenderFormat` to render the full list of files when run with `debug="true"` and only the minified version when run with `debug="false"`.

Here's an example:

```
    public ActionResult AppManifest()
    {
        string cacheFiles = "";

        cacheFiles = Scripts.RenderFormat("{0}",
            "~/bundles/jquery",
            "~/bundles/jqueryval",
            "~/bundles/bootstrap").ToString();

        cacheFiles += Styles.RenderFormat("{0}",
            "~/Content/css");

        string manifest = String.Format(@"CACHE MANIFEST

  CACHE:
  {0}", cacheFiles);

        return Content(manifest, "text/cache-manifest");
    }
```